# Google Drive 600 member limit - how close are we to reaching it?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-shared-drive

According to the following link, shared Google Drives have a membership limit of 600 combined users and groups.

https://support.google.com/a/answer/7338880?hl=en

At my organization, we have a shared drive. We are unfortunately forced to share with users individually rather than create groups due to a conflict between organizational security requirements and our particular use case.

We are automating sharing using the Google Drive API, and we have a growing number of drive members which will eventually approach the 600 number. Is there a way we can find out how many drive members we have so we know if we're in danger of hitting the limit of 600? A user would be considered a member of the drive if at least one folder or piece of content anywhere on the drive had been shared with them. There doesn't seem to be a straightforward way in the Google Drive API to query the number of users that are members of the drive.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't found a way to directly get a drive's number of members but you might be able to make use of `drives.list`'s query and search drives with `memberCount` having more than 550.

If this gets your target drive, then you should be able to estimate for how long will it get full.

You can also do a repeated query to actually get the exact number of members.

For example:

- `name contains 'name of your shared drive' and memberCount > 200`

  - if this returns your target drive, then we know it is greater than 200. Proceed with bigger `memberCount` comparison to get the actual member count
  - if this doesn't return your target drive, lessen your `memberCount` and see if it catches your target drive.
  - repeat until you get a more specific number of `memberCount`

With these in mind, you can create an algorithm that will loop the call until it matches the actual `memberCount`. But if it is a hassle for you to do this, then simply querying if your target drive is having greater than 550 members will suffice and should warn you that it is already near reaching the limit.

#### Note:

- You need to use `true` for `useDomainAdminAccess` and have administrator privileges for it to work.

#### Reference:

- [Search for shared drives](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-shareddrives)
- [Drives: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/drives/list)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I've marked it as accepted. I have now learned that we are sharing from "my drive", not creating shared drives, so I asked a question here about whether the same limitations apply, in case you know the answer.

Comment: here is the link to the related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69121648/does-the-600-member-limit-for-google-shared-drives-also-apply-to-sharing-from-m